# How to print index 0 of each nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm aware I can just use for loop to iterate through each index and access index 0 of the sublist.

for example:

```
for i in res:
        print(i[0])
```

However, I was wondering if it was possible to do something like:

```
print(*res, sep="\n")
```

Since the example above is for a normal list and not a nested list, I was wondering if there's a way to print the 0th index of values in a nested list in one line instead of using a loop.

For example **[['a', 1.0], ['b', 2.0], ['c', 2.0]]** should print: **'a,b,c'**

Let me know if I can make anything more clear, thanks.

Comment: try this `print(','.join([x[0] for x in res]))`

Comment: `next(zip(*[['a', 1.0], ['b', 2.0], ['c', 2.0]]))`

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension:

```
my_list = [['a', 1.0], ['b', 2.0], ['c', 2.0]]
print("\n".join([i[0] for i in my_list]))
```